# find the area in the first quadran

Tags: multivariable-calculus

By first making an appropriate transformation, find the area in the first quadrant which is
bounded by the curves $x = y, x = 2y, xy = 1$ and $xy = 2$

answer

$u=x \times y$;  $v=\frac{y}{x}$ (is this right?); so

$dxdy = \large{\frac{d(x,y)}{d(u,v)}}$

$\large{\frac{d(u,v)}{d(x,y)}=\frac{2y}{x}}$

$\large{\frac{d(x,y)}{d(u,v)}=(2 \times \frac{y}{x})^{-1}=\frac{x}{2} \times y =\frac{1}{2} \times v}$

$u: 1 \to2$;

$v: \frac{1}{2} \to 1$;

$A = \int \int \frac{1}{2} \times v \space \space dudv =$  ln(2)/2

is this right or did i do something wrong?

Comment: does v=y/x? thats the part i'm not sure of

Answer (score 1):

we will use the transformation $$ x = r \cos t, y = r\sin t$$ to convert the cartesian equations to polar ones. the equation $xy = 1$ is transformed to $$r^2 \cos t \sin t = 1$$ and the rays $y = x , y = 2x$ transform to $$ \tan t = 1, \tan t = \frac12. $$ the area element in polar coordinates is $$ \frac12 r^2 dt.$$

putting all these together we have the area equals $$\frac12\int_{\tan^{-1}(1/2)}^{\pi/4} \left(\frac2{\sin t\cos t }- \frac1{\sin t \cos t}\right)\, dt=  \frac14\int_{\tan^{-1}(1/2)}^{\pi/4}  \csc 2t \, dt = -\frac18\ln(\cot 2t + \csc 2t)\big|_{\tan^{-1}(1/2)}^{\pi/4}\\
= \frac18\ln\left(\frac34+ \frac53\right)\\
=\frac18\ln\left(\frac{29}{12}\right)$$

Comment: sorry, which part did you convert?

Comment: @user241340,  i converted $xy = 1$ to $r^2 = \frac1{\sin t \cos t}$

Comment: where did pi/4 n atan(1/2) come from?

Comment: $x = y$  becomes $\theta  = \pi/4$

Comment: so what i was doing up there is totally wrong?

Comment: @user241340, that is a legitimate way doing it. i did polar coordinates in my pre cal class, so i am practicing my polar coordinate skills.

Comment: can you tell everything you converted to polar coordinates?

Comment: @user241340, please see my edit.